# How to make my program take multiple std inputs and give multiple std outputs in return?

Tags: bash, shell

I was able to write this program that takes as input a "file.txt" containing this type of strings ATCGTAATTC and gives as output a second file called "compl-file.txt" containing something like that CAATTACGAT. All of that works well, but I actually need this program to take many files as inputs and give many compl-files as outputs while applying all the processes.
Thank you for your help !

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
#
##create file called compl-*
name=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/compl-\1/'`
touch $name 
##upside down
VAR1=$(tac < $1)
echo "$VAR1" > $name
##reverse
VAR2=$(rev $name)
echo "$VAR2" > $name
##replace G/C C/G
VAR3=$(sed -e 's/C/X/g; s/G/C/g; s/X/G/g' $name)
echo "$VAR3" > $name
##replace A/T T/A
VAR4=$(sed -e 's/A/Y/g; s/T/A/g; s/Y/T/g' $name)
echo "$VAR4" > $name
```

Comment: How is your `name` assignment on the first line different from `name="compl-$1"`?

Comment: Note that standard input and standard output are the names of two specific file descriptors. You can have multiple inputs, but you can't have multiple standard inputs.

Comment: @chepner thank you, I see the difference

Comment: Sidenote: instead of swapping with three substitutions, you can use `y/CG/GC/` and `y/AT/TA/`

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you for the tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many filenames can be given as parameters.  You can process each one at a time:

```
for name
do
    # Process filename here as "$name" (put the filename in double quotes)

done
```

As for output filenames, there are several ways of identifying them.  You could just add a counter to the end of the filename, a date/time stamp, or use the input filename and append "-compl" to the end.  It really depends how you need to identify each one.

By the way, in your code you continually overwrite the file, you probably want `>> "$name"` to append.